# Can't save current state progress bar in Sharedpreference preference

Tags: android, progress-bar, sharedpreferences

I have problem with save current state in progress bar in SharedPreferences.
this is my code. Problem when go with this activity and next go out with activity agian ,progress bar don't count state with stay pervious.

```
    private UpdateQrCode updateQrCode;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private static final String TIME = "Time";
```

method onCreate witch have

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

 sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

 if (sharedpreferences.contains(Time)) {
            int currentInterval = sharedpreferences.getInt(TIME, 0);
            progressBar.setMax(currentInterval);
            progressBar.setProgress(currentInterval);
        } else {
            interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalTotpDecrypt);
        }
}

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if (updateQrCode != null) {
            updateQrCode.cancel(true);
        }
    }
```

//this class asyncTask with update progress bar

```
  private class UpdateQrCode extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setMax(interval);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
            secondTimeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(values[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

            for (int i = interval; i >= 0; i--) {
                publishProgress(i);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);


            try {
                NewXorString = generateQrCodeString(otpDecrypt, path3Decrypt, intervalTotpDecrypt);
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            generateNewString = Cryptography.xorHex(NewXorString);

            UpdateQrCodeString(generateNewString);
            updateQrCode.execute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();
            updateQrCode.cancel(true);
        }
    }

 //method with save to sharedPreference 

 public void saveStateProgressBar() {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
        editor.putInt(TIME, interval);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you using `Editor` to store values in shared preferences? e.g

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("progress", loadingProgress);
editor.commit();
```